# Is it possible to define valid JavaScript's functions from Dart?

Tags: dart, dart-js-interop

Sorry for my broken English.
I'm new to the Dart language. I have been searching for a way to communicate between JS and Dart. I want to call jQueryUI code from Dart.

When I create a jQueryUI's dialog, the HTML and JS code will be like this:

### HTML code:

```dart
...
<button id="btn1">OPEN</button>
<div id="msg">
Hello, world!
</div>
...
```

### JS code:

```dart
$('#btn').click( function() {
  $('#msg').dialog('open');
});

$('#msg').dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  buttons: {
    "OK": function() {
      $(this).dialog('close');
    }
  },
  title: "Dialog",
  modal: false,
  show: 'fold',
  hide: 'puff'
});
```

So, I tried to convert these JS code into Dart code.
However, when I write these test Dart codes below, I got an error message below.

```dart
Breaking on exception: Closure call with mismatched arguments: function 'call'
```

### Dart code:

```dart
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:js' as js;

void dartFunc() {
  print("test");
}

void main() {

  js.JsObject btn = js.context.callMethod(r'$', ['#btn']);
  btn.callMethod('click', [dartFunc]); //-----> ERROR!
  //...
}
```

But, when I wrote a JS function and Dart code below, the error disappeared and the program ran successfully.

### JS code:

```dart
function jsFunc() {
  console.log("test");
}
```

### Dart code:

```dart
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:js' as js;

void dartFunc() {
  print("test");
}

void main() {

  js.JsObject btn = js.context.callMethod(r'$', ['#btn']);
  btn.callMethod('click', [jsFunc]); -----> SUCCESS!
  //...
}
```

To find out this problem, I performed some tests.
When I print both functions(jsFunc() and dartFunc()) to the console from Dart, like

### Dart code:

```dart
...
js.context['dartFunc'] = dartFunc;
print(js.context['jsFunc']);
print(js.context['dartFunc']);
...
```

the results are below.

```dart
function jsFunc() {
  console.log("test");
}
function () {
  return func(Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments));
}
```

Apparently the result of `print(js.context['dartFunc'])` is odd.

Can anyone help?
Is it possible to define valid JavaScript's functions from Dart?

Thanks for reading to the end :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Js function are allowed to be called with not the same number of parameters as the declaration. This is not the same in Dart.

Basically the callback you defined (`dartFunc`) is called with at least one argument but the function does not support argument. You can simply add optionnal arguments to your Dart function. Thus the error should disappear.

```dart
void dartFunc([arg1,arg2,arg3]) {
  print("test");
}
```

Now the function can be called with 0 to 3 parameters.

Comment: does that it mean that to interop we need to pass everything as Arrays?